# Culture name using underscore instead of dash

Tags: c#, resx, culture

In `C#`, I can build resx files for various languages/cultures using the standing ISO naming convention (i.e., `Strings.resx`, `Strings.en-GB.resx`, `Strings.fr.resx`).  When I compile, I get a corresponding folders for each of the culture-specific resx files. My dilemma is with the naming convention used.

MS uses "the format languagecode2-country/regioncode2, where languagecode2 is a lowercase two-letter code derived from `ISO 639-1` and country/regioncode2 is an uppercase two-letter code derived from `ISO 3166`."

Because of some interactions with other components in my company that I have little control over, I need use an underscore (_), like this: languagecode2_country/regioncode2.  For example, instead of `"en-GB"`, I need `"en_GB"`.  The goal is to get my app to look for the resource file in a folder named `en_GB` whenever the culture on system is set to `"en-GB"`.

Is this possible?  I haven't found an ISO specification for the separator, so if that's out there, I may be able to use that as ammo to fix the real problem and follow the standard among the other components I am using.

Note, when I access a localized resource within the app, I do so via an auto-generated property in the`designer.cs` file, so I can't just replace `"en-GB"` with `"en_GB"`.

Comment: The separator syntax is described in RFC 3066 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt - chapter 2.1: Language tag syntax. I would strongly suggest to get rid of these funky underscores :-)

Comment: This just isn't going to work, the resource manager will always use a dash, never an underscore to find the satellite assembly.  This cannot be changed.  Very unclear why this restriction exists, nothing that a simple String.Replace() couldn't fix.

Comment: Thanks Simon and Hans.  Hopefully I can get the rest of the business to follow standard naming and use the "-".